# Rendering Backbone.js Collection as a select list

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to render a Backbone.js collection as a `select` list using an Underscore.js template, and the list isn't getting populated. The `select` element is displaying, but there are no `options`.

I have confirmed that I'm able to pass individual properties into my template and render them as `label` elements, so the issue must be how I'm trying to handle the collection.

Here's my Backbone code:

```
Rate = Backbone.Model.extend({
    duration : null
});

Rates = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function (model, options) {
    }
});

AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#rate-editor-container'),
    initialize: function () {
      this.rates = new Rates(null, { view: this } );

      this.rates.add(new Rate ({ duration: "Not Set" }));
      this.rates.add(new Rate ({ duration: "Weekly" }));
      this.rates.add(new Rate ({ duration: "Monthly" }));

      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      var rate_select_template = _.template($("#rate_select_template").html(), {rates: this.rates, labelValue: 'Something' });
      $('#rate-editor-container').html(rate_select_template);
    },
});

var appview = new AppView();
```

And my template:

```xml
<script type="text/template" id="rate_select_template">
  <select id="rate-selector"></select>
  <% _(rates).each(function(rate) { %>
    <option value="<%= rate.duration %>"><%= rate.duration %></option>
  <% }); %>
</script>

<div id="rate-editor-container"></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Double check the value of 'this' in your render function- I don't see you binding it to the Backbone object. You can do it with _.bindAll(this, 'render') in your initializer function.

Comment: Hmmm. I added that right above `this.render()` in my `Backbone.View` extension, but it didn't seem to do anything. Before I posted my question, I did `console.log(this.rates)` and it outputted as `child` with three sub-objects. So I think I'm passing an object of some kind with three objects nested under it, which seems right.

Comment: @Factor: `delegateEvents` in recent versions of Backbone does the binding by itself (look for `method = _.bind(method, this);` inside `delegateEvents` in the [latest source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js)) so you no longer need the usual `_.bindAll` dance to start your `initialize` methods.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have a couple different problems.

1. Your template is trying to put the `<option>` elements *after* the `<select>` instead of *inside* it. This will produce invalid HTML and the browser will butcher that once you get anything out of your template.
2. `rates` is a Backbone collection so it already has access to [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#each) [`each`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods); wrapping it as `_(rates)` just confuses Underscore and prevents any iterations from happening.
3. Inside the iteration, `rate` is a Backbone model instance so it won't have a `duration` property, you have to say `rate.get('duration')`.

Your template should look more like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="rate_select_template">
    <select id="rate-selector">
        <% rates.each(function(rate) { %>
            <option value="<%= rate.get('duration') %>"><%= rate.get('duration') %></option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AEqjn/

Alternatively, you can just fix the nesting error in your template to produce valid HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="rate_select_template">
    <select id="rate-selector">
        <% _(rates).each(function(rate) { %>
            <option value="<%= rate.duration %>"><%= rate.duration %></option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

and use [`toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) in your view to feed raw data to your template rather than the collection itself:

```
var rate_select_template = _.template($("#rate_select_template").html(), {
    rates: this.rates.toJSON(),
    labelValue: 'Something'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VAxFW/

I think the latter one is what you were aiming for as that would a more standard approach to working with templates in Backbone.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clear explanations. Can't believe that I missed the issue with the `select` nesting. Ugh. Backbone.js seems like it'll be great, but it's impossible to find examples for some really basic stuff like this. There's a lot going on in sample apps like the todo app, and it's hard to see what each piece does. I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @Josh: It is nice to work with once you figure out the basic patterns, of course the only way to figure out the basic patterns is to make mistaeks.