# Return a collection inside a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've got a collection of models with different properties and I need to render some of them inside the `<select>` tag, each model as an `<option>`. The view that renders this collection is nested in another view. Here is my collection:

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',

    developers: function () {
        var developers = this.where({role: "developer"});
        return new UserCollection(developers);
    }
});
```

And this is my view for the `select` tag:

```
var InterviewersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template(interviewersTemplate);
        this.collection = new UserCollection();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.interviewers = this.collection.developers();
    },

    render: function () {   
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});
```

and this is my template:

```
<label>Interviewer</label>
<select class="form-control" id="js-interviewer-selector">
    <% _.each(this.interviewers.toJSON(), function(interviewer) { %>
      <option value="<%= interviewer.login %>">
        <%= interviewer.firstName %> <%= interviewer.lastName %>
      </option>
    <% }) %>
</select>
```

The template renders inside another view properly and exactly as I need, but there's no options inside the `select` tag and it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

[Repo with my project](https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/hr-dashboard)

Comment: try adding semicolon ; at the end of each method .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154628/rendering-backbone-js-collection-as-a-select-list

Comment: @mahendrapratapjewaria I've already looked up at that question and answer, but unfortunately that wasn't helpful enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was the same as in this question -- because of asynchronous nature of `.fetch()` method the collection was loaded after the view was rendered, so it received nothing. So, removing `.fetch()` method from `initialize` and adding it to `render` worked. Here's the complete code:

```
var InterviewersSelect = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template(interviewersTemplate);
        this.collection = new UserCollection();
    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.collection.fetch({
            data: {
                role: "developer"
            },

            success: function(collection) {
                var interviewers = collection.map(function(item) {
                    return item.toJSON();
                });
                self.$el.html(self.template({interviewers: interviewers}));
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  to pass your collection to your view like this

```
render: function () { 
    var that  = this;
    that.$el.html(that.template({interviewers: that.interviewers}));
    return this;
}
```

and in your template use underscore _.each function to dive collection to individual interviwer like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="js-interviewer-selector">
<% _.each(interviewers, function(interviewer) { %>
  <option value="<%= interviewer.login %>">
    <%= interviewer.firstName %> <%= interviewer.lastName %>
  </option>
<% }) %>
</select>
```

It must work now:)

Comment: That can only mean that you are not receiving any response from your json(fake server)

Comment: I'm getting response from my server and it is OK, but there's just nothing displayed inside the view.